# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Tags: tokens

Tengo este error al obtener el formato de una fecha, adapté mi fecha con `simple date format` y no obtengo mi resultado:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 2017 near line 1, column 101 [SELECT v FROM com.sa.model.crm.Oferente v WHERE 1 = 1 AND v.tipoOferente= 0 AND v.fechaDeEntrevista 2017-00-07]at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:31)at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:24)at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:59)at

Este es mi método:

```
public void FiltrarPorTipo (){


     Date d = getFechaDeEntrevista();
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
             String d2 = format.format(d);
     System.out.println(d2);


    hql = "SELECT v FROM Oferente v WHERE 1 = 1";
    hql +=(getTipoOferente() != null)? " AND v.tipoOferente= "+ getTipoOferente():"";

    hql +=(getFechaDeEntrevista()!= null)? " AND v.fechaDeEntrevista "+ d2:"";



    oferentePorTipoDias = entityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList();

    System.out.println("************ Consulta: " + hql);

    dtRp.put("oferentePorTipoDias", oferentePorTipoDias);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error que se observa a simple vista es que en el último `AND` al parecer no se le está añadiendo el `=`  , es decir `v.fechaDeEntrevista = ...`

```
hql +=(getFechaDeEntrevista()!= null)? " AND v.fechaDeEntrevista =  "+ d2:"";
```

Comment: fijate que tengo un nuevo problema:      
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: date = integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @NestorMelara edite su pregunta o realice otra, sería bueno que imprima  su variable `hql` , y  coloqué en su pregunta el resultado así podemos verificar errores.